# HTML element is invisible in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am running WordPress 5.2 on the default theme and made a custom nav bar where I used CSS so the dropdown menu is invisible unless its parent is hovered over. Recently it stopped working (when I hover over it doesn't appear).

When I use the Chrome console to turn the `element:hover` on and inspect the dropdown menu, it shows the element is there (CSS attribute `display` is indeed set to `block` instead of `none`). I checked `z-index` and `opacity` (2 and 1 respectively) so I don't think that is the issue.

http://ess.ccmcanada.org

**Page while inspecting element:**
[image: screenshot of page while inspecting element]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `overflow-y: hidden` from `#main-nav`, because this is hiding the `dropdown menus` that are outside its dimensions.

Remember: common `properties` that may be hiding an `element` that you can investigate are usually these: `display`, `visibility`, `position`, `z-index`, `opacity`, `transform` and `overflow`.